# How to split a CSV into a dataframe without newline

Tags: pyspark, csv

Currently I'm using pyspark to make my df from a csv. However when I take the data in, it puts each element on a new line. Is there any way to keep the elements separate, and keep them on the same line?

```
#Loads the data in the textfile
df = sc.textFile("data.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
df.take(1)

[['2',

  '20200118',

  '0',

  'AE',

  'ABV',

  'AUH',

  '20200416',

  '0',
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the output of the `df.take(1)` as it printed is also the actual structure of your data, meaning that it is actually not including the new lines in it i.e: `[['2', '20200118', '0', 'AE', 'ABV', 'AUH', '20200416', '0', ...], [row_2...]]` Did you try assigning it to a df to see if the new lines are of elements or of the rows?

Comment: Have you tried to use the pandas.read_csv?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a matrix, all items are grouped by row.

A very small example:

```
csv:
a,b
c,d
```

Will become:

```
[['a','b'],['c','d']]
```

The formatting of the output is indeed misleading.